Diagramm or Graphical representation (canvas)
I've had a problem with a script for a few days now. The script processes a CSV file and displays it as a diagram. Unfortunately, when my code processes the data, no diagram (bar or line diagram) is displayed.
I want to get 2 diagrams for all the data from the CSV at the end and then I should also have a diagram for each selected display name. If you test this code and process the data from the CSV file, you will see the selection list. As I said, unfortunately I don't see any diagrams.


document.getElementById('home').addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location.href = 'https://datenlotsen.de';
});

document.getElementById('anzeigenBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  updateChart();
  updateSummaryChart();
});

document.getElementById('nextPage').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('firstPage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('secondPage').style.display = 'block';
});

document.getElementById('prevPage1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('secondPage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('firstPage').style.display = 'block';
});

document.getElementById('nextPage2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('secondPage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('thirdPage').style.display = 'block';
});

document.getElementById('prevPage2').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('thirdPage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('secondPage').style.display = 'block';
});

document.getElementById('prevPage3').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('thirdPage').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('secondPage').style.display = 'block';
});

let lines = [];
const yLabels = [
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  'D',
  'E',
  'F',
  'G',
  'H',
  'I',
  'J',
  'K',
  'L',
  'M',
  'N',
  'O',
  'P',
  'Q',
  'R',
  'S',
  'T',
  'U',
  'V',
  'W',
  'X',
  'Y',
  'Z',

];



function processData(csv) {
  const allLines = csv.split('\n');
  lines = allLines.slice(1); // Überschrift entfernen
  const anzeigenameSet = new Set();
  lines.forEach(line => {
    const [, , , , , anzeigename] = line.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
    anzeigenameSet.add(anzeigename);
  });
  const anzeigenameSelect = document.getElementById('anzeigename');
  anzeigenameSet.forEach(name => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = name;
    option.text = name;
    anzeigenameSelect.appendChild(option);
  });
}

function updateChart() {
  const startDate = document.getElementById('startDatum').value;
  const endDate = document.getElementById('endDatum').value;
  const anzeigename = document.getElementById('anzeigename').value;
  const filteredData = lines.filter(line => {
    const [datum, , , , , name] = line.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
    const isWithinDateRange = (!startDate || datum >= startDate) && (!endDate || datum <= endDate);
    const isMatchingAnzeigename = !anzeigename || name === anzeigename;
    return isWithinDateRange && isMatchingAnzeigename;
  });
  const chartData = prepareChartData(filteredData);
  updateBarChart(chartData);
  updateLineChart(chartData);
  document.querySelector('.page-navigation').style.display = 'flex';
}

function updateSummaryChart() {
  const startDate = document.getElementById('startDatum').value;
  const endDate = document.getElementById('endDatum').value;
  const anzeigename = document.getElementById('anzeigename').value;


  const filteredData = lines.filter(line => {
    const [datum, , , , , name] = line.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
    const isWithinDateRange = (!startDate || datum >= startDate) && (!endDate || datum <= endDate);
    const isMatchingAnzeigename = !anzeigename || name === anzeigename;
    return isWithinDateRange && isMatchingAnzeigename;
  });
  const summaryChartData = prepareSummaryChartData(filteredData);
  updateSummaryBarChart(summaryChartData);
}

function prepareChartData(data) {
  const aggregatedData = aggregateData(data);
  const labels = yLabels.sort(sortLabels);
  const datasets = [{
      label: 'Neu',
      backgroundColor: '#76b7b2',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 2)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: []
    },
    {
      label: 'Gelesen',
      backgroundColor: '#ff7f0e',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 2)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: []
    },
    {
      label: 'Geändert',
      backgroundColor: '#aec7e8',
      borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 2)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: []
    },
    {
      label: 'Gelöscht',
      backgroundColor: '#ffbb78',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 2)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: []
    }
  ];
  labels.forEach(label => {
    const labelData = aggregatedData[label] || {};
    datasets.forEach(dataset => {
      dataset.data.push(labelData[dataset.label] || 0);
    });
  });
  return {
    labels,
    datasets
  };
}

function prepareSummaryChartData(data) {
  const aggregatedData = aggregateData(data);
  const labels = yLabels.sort(sortLabels);
  const summaryData = labels.map(label => {
    const labelData = aggregatedData[label] || {};
    return Object.values(labelData).reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0);
  });
  return {
    labels,
    summaryData
  };
}

function aggregateData(data) {
  const aggregatedData = {};
  data.forEach(line => {
    const [datum, art, , typ] = line.split(',').map(item => item.trim());
    if (!aggregatedData[typ]) {
      aggregatedData[typ] = {
        'Neu': 0,
        'Gelesen': 0,
        'Geändert': 0,
        'Gelöscht': 0
      };
    }
    aggregatedData[typ][art] += 1;
  });
  return aggregatedData;
}

function sortLabels(a, b) {
  const germanTerms = ['Vertrag-Dokument', 'Rechnung-Dokument'];
  const indexA = germanTerms.indexOf(a);
  const indexB = germanTerms.indexOf(b);
  return indexA - indexB;
}

let barChart, lineChart, summaryBarChart;

function updateBarChart(data) {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('barChart').getContext('2d');
  if (barChart) barChart.destroy();
  barChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          color: 'white',
          display: function(context) {
            return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== 0; // Nur Werte anzeigen, die nicht 0 sind
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function updateLineChart(data) {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('lineChart').getContext('2d');
  if (lineChart) lineChart.destroy();
  lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

function updateSummaryBarChart(data) {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('summaryBarChart').getContext('2d');
  if (summaryBarChart) summaryBarChart.destroy();
  summaryBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: data.labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Gesamtzahl der Ereignisse',
        backgroundColor: '#4caf50',
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 2)',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: data.summaryData
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          color: 'white',
          display: function(context) {
            return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== 0; // Nur Werte anzeigen, die nicht 0 sind
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById('csvInput').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      processData(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
});
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #c0d8ff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1340px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-height: 1600px;
  /* Set initial max-height to 500px */
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Prevent scrollbars */
}

.container.expanded {
  max-height: 2000px;
  /* Increase max-height when expanded */
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #b5dcb3;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.header h2 {
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.header button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.btn {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  /* Adjust width for larger button */
  height: 40px;
  /* Adjust height for larger button */
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.btn i {
  font-size: 24px;
  /* Adjust icon size */
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

.select-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.select-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
}

input[type="file"],
input[type="date"],
select {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="file"] {
  border: none;
  /* Linie um das Eingabefeld entfernen */
}

select,
input[type="date"],
button {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

button {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

#anzeigenBtn {
  width: 160px;
  /* Neue Breite für die Taste */
  height: 30px;
}

.charts-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.chart-column {
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.page-navigation {
  display: flex;
  /* Initial display set to flex */
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* New style for the second and third page */

#secondPage,
#thirdPage {
  overflow: visible;
  /* Ensure content is visible */
  max-height: none;
  /* Allow content to expand */
  height: auto;
  /* Adjust height automatically */
}


/* Make the button invisible */

#prevPage2 {
  display: none;
}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container" id="firstPage">
  <div class="header">
    <button class="btn" id="home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></button>
    <h2>Statistische</h2>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-width: 1px;">
  <div class="select-container" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">
    <div>
      <label for="csvInput" style="margin-left: 20px;">Datei auswählen:</label>
      <input type="file" id="csvInput" accept=".csv">
    </div>
    <div class="select-group">
      <label for="anzeigename">Anzeigename:</label>
      <select id="anzeigename">
        <option value="">Alle</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="select-container" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">
      <div class="select-group">
        <label for="startDatum">Startdatum:</label>
        <input type="date" id="startDatum">
      </div>
      <div class="select-group" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">
        <label for="endDatum">Enddatum:</label>
        <input type="date" id="endDatum">
      </div>
      <button id="anzeigenBtn" style="margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 1px;">Anzeigen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-width: 1px;">
  <div class="charts-row">
    <div class="chart-column">
      <canvas id="barChart"></canvas>
      <h3 id="barChartTitle" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;"></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-width: 1px;">
  <div class="page-navigation">
    <button id="nextPage">Zur nächsten Seite</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="secondPage" style="display: none;">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Statistische</h2>
  </div>
  <hr style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <div class="charts-row">
    <div class="chart-column">
      <canvas id="lineChart"></canvas>
      <h3 id="lineChartTitle" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;"></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-width: 1px;">
  <div class="page-navigation">
    <button id="prevPage1">Zurück zur ersten Seite</button>
    <button id="nextPage2">Zur nächsten Seite</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="thirdPage" style="display: none;">
  <div class="header">
    <button id="prevPage2">Zurück zur zweiten Seite</button>
    <h2>Statistische</h2>
  </div>
  <hr style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <div class="charts-row">
    <div class="chart-column">
      <h3 id="summaryTitle"></h3>
      <canvas id="summaryBarChart"></canvas>
      <h3 id="summaryBarChartTitle" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;"></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border-width: 1px;">
  <div class="page-navigation">
    <button id="prevPage3">Zurück zur zweiten Seite</button>
  </div>
</div>



The CSV file looks like this
Date,neu,gelesen,geaendert,geloescht,Anzeigename
2024-03-07,0,3,0,0,A
2024-03-07,0,1,57,0,B
2024-03-07,0,2,0,0,C
2024-03-07,0,1,0,9,D
2024-03-07,1,20,8,0,E
2024-03-07,0,7,0,0,F
2024-03-07,0,1,0,0,G
2024-03-07,23,1,0,0,H
2024-03-07,293,10,0,160,I
2024-03-07,0,3,0,20,XSAP J
2024-03-11,0,110,0,0,K
2024-03-11,0,2,0,0,L
2024-03-11,40,4,0,0,M
2024-03-11,0,4,0,0,N
2024-03-11,0,14,0,25,O
2024-03-11,0,2,0,0,P
2024-03-11,0,2,10,0,Q
2024-03-11,0,6,0,0,R
2024-03-11,523,2,10,150,S
2024-03-13,0,16,2,9,T
2024-03-13,0,4,0,0,U
2024-03-13,0,4,0,0,V
2024-03-13,0,14,0,0,W
2024-03-13,0,2,0,18,X
2024-03-13,0,2,0,0,Y
2024-03-13,20,6,0,0,Z

